Why is the public version of my notification not showing on the lock screen in Android Studio Java?
I'm working on an Android app using Android Studio and Java. I have implemented two notifications for medication reminders: one public and one private. The public notification is supposed to show on the lock screen, but for some reason, it's not appearing.  Here's how I'm creating the notifications:
NotificationCompat.Builder publicNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                        .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.notification))
                        .setContentText(publicMessage)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(publicMessage))
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
                        .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                        .setContentIntent(actionPendingIntent);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                          .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.notification))
                        .setContentText(message)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
                        .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE)
                        .setPublicVersion(publicNotificationBuilder.build())
                        .setContentIntent(actionPendingIntent);

NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
notificationManager.notify((int) notification.getId(), notificationBuilder.build());

I've ensured that the public notification is created with setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC) and settled as setPublicVersion(), but it's still not showing on the lock screen. The private notification (i.e. notificationBuilder.build()) is always shown on the lock screen, not the public version. What could be causing this issue? Is there something I'm missing or misunderstanding about how to display public notifications on the lock screen?

Have you checked the Android system setting what is configured regarding which notification messages are allowed to be shown on the lock screen?

What do you mean with "which notification messages are allowed to be shown on the lock screen"? The private version it's always shown, but not the public version.

You sure that they have different IDs? Better replace notification.getId() with two constants. You probably would also require two notification channels, so that one can manage them individually.

In my Android 13 device I have a setting Notifications on Lock Screen with three options from "show all messages", "hide silent messages" up to "show no messages".

I don't understand your point, the notification is being shown on the lock screen. The thing is that I want to hide part of the notification that's why I am using a public version (that never shows, only the "basic" private notification)
